# Reading JSON file with Swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift

With this code i can show the "result"

```
var movies: [NSDictionary]?
var dates: NSDictionary?

func fetchNowPlayingMovies(){
        let apiKey = "8e3967947a95555f9c430e68d070a0e7"
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=\(apiKey)"+"&language=en-US&page=1")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
        let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
        let task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(dataOrNil, reponse, error) in
            if let data = dataOrNil{
                if let responseDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                    //print("reponse: \(responseDictionary)")
                    self.movies = responseDictionary["results"] as? [NSDictionary]
                    self.dates = responseDictionary["dates"] as? NSDictionary
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieCell", for: indexPath) as! MovieTableViewCell

        //MARK: - JSON Properties
        let movie = movies![indexPath.row]
        let date = dates![indexPath.row]

        let title = movie["title"] as! String
        let vote_average = movie["vote_average"] as! Double
        let overview = movie["overview"] as! String

        let baseUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500"
        let posterPath = movie["poster_path"] as! String

        let imageUrl = URL(string: baseUrl + posterPath)

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.lblTitle.text = title

        cell.lblOverview.text = overview

        cell.lblVoteAVG.text = String(vote_average)
        cell.imgPosterPath.sd_setImage(with: imageUrl)

        return cell
    }
```

Request: https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=8e3967947a95555f9c430e68d070a0e7&language=en-US&page=1
How i can get the "page" and the "maximum" in "dates"?
Thank you!

Comment: Do not post screenshot of code. Copy/past real code. Avoid `NSDictionary` in Swift3, prefers Swifty Types Dictionary. Page is at the same level as results, so responseDictionary["page"]? Same for the dates.

Comment: I'm a newbie so I don't understand very well. Can you explain with code? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var movies: [NSDictionary]?
var dates: NSDictionary?

var page: Int? // var for page
var maximum: String? // var for maximum in dates

func fetchNowPlayingMovies(){
    let apiKey = "8e3967947a95555f9c430e68d070a0e7"
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=\(apiKey)"+"&language=en-US&page=1")
    let request = URLRequest(url: url! as URL, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
    let session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    let task: URLSessionDataTask = session.dataTask(with:request, completionHandler: {(dataOrNil, reponse, error) in
        if let data = dataOrNil{
            if let responseDictionary = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
                //print("reponse: \(responseDictionary)")
                self.movies = responseDictionary["results"] as? [NSDictionary]
                self.dates = responseDictionary["dates"] as? NSDictionary

                // This is how you get to page
                print("page: \(responseDictionary["page"]!)")
                self.page = responseDictionary["page"] as? Int
                print("page: \(self.page!)")

                // This is how you get to maximum in dates
                self.maximum = self.dates?["maximum"] as? String
                print("maximum: \(self.maximum!)")

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

I hope it helped

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.
Please vote up to my answer and click on the check mark beside the answer if it helped you. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)